# JS import() with query

Tags: javascript, import

I just discovered that the following is valid js

```
import('./m.mjs?i=1')
```

I believe that the part after `?` is called a query, however, I cannot find documentation.

Where can I find documentation regarding the query feature?

Comment: https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-writing

Comment: It is not `valid JS` is it a string containing a valid relative URL